# Generate all 3 letter words at least with 1 vowel in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to generate all 3 letter words at least with 1 vowel.
I have already made a code to generate all words with 3 letters but I can't find how out to make every word with 1 vowel or more.
This is my code:

```
alfabeto = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
alfabeto2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
alfabeto3 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

small = [alfabeto ++ alfabeto2 ++ alfabeto3 | alfabeto <- alfabeto, alfabeto2 <- alfabeto2, alfabeto3 <- alfabeto3]
```

Comment: Start with generating words with three characters that *start* with a vowel and then two characters, then a vowel in the middle, and then a vowel in the end.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to repeat the same list three times in the code. Just define it once and use `[ x++y++z | x <- alfabeto, y <- alfabeto, z <- alfabeto ]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The problem is that the first 10 words have to be: ["aaa","aab","aac","aad","aae","aaf","aag","aah","aai","aaj"] and by that way doesn't work.

Comment: @chi Ty, it helped a lot

Comment: @JohnSmith: I would not worry about that at the moment, first try to practice with some related problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define two alfabets, one with only vowels, and one with all characters:

```
vowels :: [Char]
vowels = "aeiouy"

letters :: [Char]
letters = [ 'a' .. 'z' ]
```

now for the result, the two first characters can be chosen both from the `letters` list, since regardless what we choose, for the last character we can pick a vowel of both are not vowels.

We thus can define a function that, given the first two characters, returns a list of vowels (if both characters are not vowels), or a list of letters (if at least one of the characters is a vowel). That function looks like:

```
pickThird :: Char -> Char -> [Char]
pickThird la lb
    | … = letters
    | otherwise = vowels
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` part.

Now we can use this in a list comprehension that looks like:

```
words3 :: [String]
words3 = [ [la, lb, lc] | la <- letters, lb <- letters, lc <- pickThird la lb ]
```

the `pickThird` will thus, depending on the choices of `la` and `lb` either return a list of all letters, or only the vowels.